# Using QWebkit to retrieve divs with a specific class

Tags: html, qt, qt4.7, qwebkit

I posted the question below, trying to use the QDomDocument classes. I was advised to use the QWebkit instead, but I'm very confused how to do what I need to do with QWebkit. I've never used it before so I'm rather unsure with it. Could anyone please offer any advice? Thanks!
For the record, the function is using a QByteArray that when translated to text is a standard HTML file.

---

ORIGINAL QUESTION:

I have several divs in an HTML file with different classes, like this:

```
<div class='A'>...</div>
<div class='B'>...</div>
<div class='C'>...</div>
```

I have a Qt (4.7) program where I need to be able to get a certain div out of this based on the class. I need to use QDomDocument in this program. I know from the documentation that that class has a function `elementById()`, but I can't get that to work with classes, just ids. This isn't a HTML file a made or anything, so I don't have any control over whether it's class or id. Is there a way to do this that I'm missing? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**.pro**

```
QT += webkitwidgets
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QWebView>
#include <QWebFrame>
#include <QWebElement>

int main( int argc, char *argv[] ) {
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString l_html( "<html><body>"
                    "<div class='A'>div with class A</div>"
                    "<div class='B'>div with class B</div>"
                    "<div class='C'>div with class C</div>"
                    "<span class='A'>span with class A</span>"
                    "</body></html>" );

    QWebView l_webView; // you can skip the QWebView if you dont want to show any widget
    l_webView.page()->mainFrame()->setHtml( l_html );
    QWebElement l_root( l_webView.page()->mainFrame()->documentElement() );
    QWebElementCollection l_elements( l_root.findAll( ".a" ) );

    foreach ( QWebElement l_e, l_elements ) {
        // do what you want here
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried this but the QWebElementCollection l_elements keeps returning nothing :( Is there another arguement for findAll() that may work better?

Comment: @thnkwthprtls The code I gave is working, just put a `qDebug() << l_e.toOuterXml();` inside that foreach and you will see. About the "other argument", you can put whatever CSS selector you want.

Comment: Oh ok, that's the part I was doing incorrectly, I misunderstood the meaning of the parameter for findAll, looks like it works now. Thanks!